# EL error when trying to access parameter with multiple values

Tags: java, jsp, el

```
<form action=”TestBean.jsp”>
Name: <input type=”text” name=”name”>
ID#: <input type=”text” name=”empID”>
First food: <input type=”text” name=”food”>
Second food: <input type=”text” name=”food”> 
<input type=”submit”> 
</form>
```

in the jsp i'm trying to do this

```
First food request param: ${param.food[0]} <br>
Second food request param: ${param.food[1]} <br>
```

I get this error, when I try to run it

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Comment: have a try like <%=request.getParameterValues("food")[0]%>

Comment: I do not see a problem with the expressions. What does `${paramValues.food}` print? I would expect something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@1d261c86`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do

```
First food request param: ${param.food[0]} <br>
Second food request param: ${param.food[1]} <br>
```

instead

```
First food request param: ${paramValues.food[0]} <br>
Second food request param: ${paramValues.food[1]} <br>
```

changing param.food[0] to paramValues.food[0] solves the issue.